# GDB Function arguments from assembly

Tags: assembly, gdb, g++, x86-64, gnu-assembler

I'm trying to find out how stack pointer affects GDB ability to get the value of passed function arguments.

I created this deliberately broken c++ code:

```
int *wtf = 0;
extern "C" void noFrame(int a, int b, int c);
extern "C" {
    void frame(int a, int b, int c) {
        *wtf=7;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    noFrame(1,2,3);
    return 0;
}
```

And assembly code

```
.code64
.text
.globl noFrame
.extern frame
noFrame:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp
    mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
    mov    %esi,-0x8(%rbp)
    mov    %edx,-0xc(%rbp)
    callq frame
    popq %rbp
    ret
```

It was tailored to resemble the g++ generated one:

```
objdump -d ./program
...
00000000000007c0 <noFrame>:
 7c0:   55                      push   %rbp
 7c1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 7c4:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
 7c7:   89 75 f8                mov    %esi,-0x8(%rbp)
 7ca:   89 55 f4                mov    %edx,-0xc(%rbp)
 7cd:   e8 02 00 00 00          callq  7d4 <frame>
 7d2:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 7d3:   c3                      retq   

00000000000007d4 <frame>:
 7d4:   55                      push   %rbp
 7d5:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 7d8:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
 7db:   89 75 f8                mov    %esi,-0x8(%rbp)
 7de:   89 55 f4                mov    %edx,-0xc(%rbp)
 7e1:   48 8b 05 58 08 20 00    mov    0x200858(%rip),%rax        # 201040 <wtf>
 7e8:   c7 00 07 00 00 00       movl   $0x7,(%rax)
 7ee:   90                      nop
 7ef:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 7f0:   c3                      retq
```

You can see, both assembly code is very similar.
But when I run it with gdb:

```
(gdb) run
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00005555555547e8 in frame (a=1, b=2, c=3) at main.cpp:11
11          *wtf=7;
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00005555555547e8 in frame (a=1, b=2, c=3) at main.cpp:11
#1  0x00005555555547d2 in noFrame () at frame.s:24
#2  0x0000555555554814 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe058) at main.cpp:18
```

You can see that GDB can find out function argument for `frame`, but not for `noFrame`, and idea why is it so?

I'm compiling code on AMD64 architecture and both g++ and as have `-g` switch enabled.

Comment: The `-g` includes that information for the compiler generated version.

Comment: @Ped7g this is x86-64 where arguments are passed in registers. Saving stuff into the red zone before a function call is however pointless (but harmless).

Comment: While the machine code is similar, the assembly code produced by g++ probably included DWARF info containing the name, type, and location expression of each function parameter.

Comment: I deliberatelly wanted to pass the same arguments that were called to noFrame, and since they are already in registers.
I added the mov's because I somehow thought it might be what GDB requires for some reason, not sure why compiler generated "frame" function that way, but there were no optimization flags added.
So if I'm getting this correctly, making assembly function means that I can forget about arguments view in GDB?

Comment: @Jester oh... AT&T syntax got me again, I misread the "store into stack" as "read from stack" ... :/ I hate that thing. :D  Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Run `g++ -S -g` on your C++ program, which will produce a `.s` file. Look at the data that follows the `.section .debug_info` directive. That's what gdb uses to determine arg info (among other things).

Comment: I was thinking, since DWARF was mentioned by @MarkPlotnick, how GDB knewed that the variables are called "a","b","c".
And as you suggested I generated assembly code from C++ code and I saw what I believe that information in "debug_info" section, also there were some CFI directives.
Since writing "debug_info" section is not feasible to do manually, I have to conclude that by writing assembly manually I loose some debugging information.
Thanks.

Comment: Related: [Dwarf hello world assembly example or tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930801/dwarf-hello-world-assembly-example-or-tutoral). The answer points to a tcl script included with gdb's test suite that can generate DWARF assembly language directives given relatively high-level input. You'll need a basic  understanding of DWARF to use it, but it's simpler than emitting a bunch of `.byte` and `.uleb128` directives yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look, it might be beneficial to spend some time in understanding how dwarf works.